# Search folder find string between two strings in multiple files and output to a new file

Tags: powershell

Example Text

> DESKTOP HARD DRIVE (S/N:9VMJ31W0)

I would like to find the text in the file

> 9VMJ31W0

Additional Example Text

> SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:3NM2Y5HB)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:3NM2YXBD)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:6SD1MZFE)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:3NM2YX1Q)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:6SD1E8SA)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:3NM305ZQ)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:B365P760VG2F)
>   SERVER HARD DRIVE (S/N:B365P760VG54)

I would like the output file to read something like this

> 3NM2Y5HB
>   3NM2YXBD
>   6SD1MZFE
>   3NM2YX1Q
>   6SD1E8SA
>   3NM305ZQ
>   B365P760VG2F
>   B365P760VG54

then output this to a file in PowerShell preferably.

The files will be located in a specific folder, searching sub folders would be awesome but not necessary.
The output would be a single multiple lined .txt file.

Does anyone have an example file I could use to perform this? I found lots of things similar but nothing I was able to actually complete the whole task with.

```
#Clear output variable
$Output = @()

#Get your files
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "*" -Exclude "Output.txt"

#Loop through files
$Files | ForEach-Object {
  #Use Regular expression to match the desired serial number string
  $Matched = Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -AllMatches 'S\/N:([A-Za-z0-9]*)'

  #Loop through the matched strings
  $Matched | ForEach-Object {
    #Save to $Output the grouped (inner) string i.e. you want "9VMJ31W0" not "S/N:9VMJ31W0"
    $Output += $_.Matches.Groups.Value
  }
}

#Write output to file
$Output | Out-File Output.txt
```

Comment: do you have any examples that you have started with?

Comment: added what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

A little searching pointed me to powershell's `SubString` method when dealing with strings.  See [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee692804.aspx) for more information about strings.

```
PS C:\Scripts\updates> $f = gc C:\Scripts\p.txt

PS C:\Scripts\updates> $f
DESKTOP HARD DRIVE (S/N:9VMJ31W0)
DESKTOP HARD DRIVE (S/N:9VMJ31W1)
DESKTOP HARD DRIVE (S/N:9VMJ31W2)

PS C:\Scripts\updates> $f | GM
(Truncated)
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), str

PS C:\Scripts\updates> $f.substring(24,8) | out-file C:\Temp\HDDSerials.txt

PS C:\Scripts\updates> Get-Content C:\Temp\HDDSerials.txt
9VMJ31W0
9VMJ31W1
9VMJ31W2
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this will output all the lines that contain "DESKTOP HARD DRIVE" in all the files in "D:\MyFolder" and subfolders (-Recurse) and append them to "D:\MyFolder\Output.txt".

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "D:\MyFolder" -Exclude "Output.txt" |
% {Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object {$_ -like '*DESKTOP HARD DRIVE*'} |
Select-Object} | Out-File "D:\MyFolder\Output.txt"
```

Best to send output to a separate folder, or use the -Exclude to exclude it from being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are the way to do this as it doesn't matter where in the file the Serial number is, it will find it:

```
#Clear output variable
$Output = @()

#Get your files
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "*" -Exclude "Output.txt"

#Loop through files
$Files | ForEach-Object {
    #Use Regular expression to match the desired serial number string
    $Matched = Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -AllMatches 'S\/N:([A-Za-z0-9]*)'

    #Loop through the matched strings
    $Matched | ForEach-Object {
        #Save to $Output the grouped (inner) string i.e. you want "9VMJ31W0" not "S/N:9VMJ31W0"
        $Output += $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    }
}

#Write output to file
$Output | Out-File Output.txt
```

If you want to more specifically match "DESKTOP HARD DRIVE (S/N:9VMJ31W0)" and not *just* "S/N:9VMJ31W0" then you change the matches to:

```
Select-String -AllMatches 'DESKTOP HARD DRIVE \(S\/N:([A-Za-z0-9]*)\)'
```

Comment: I attempted this however I am not getting any output, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with the code you provided.
I removed the [1] from groups and got this to run however I don't get any results.

Comment: Make sure that you are running this code in the same folder that you have the file. I created a text file with your example text, saved it to C:\temp. I changed the powershell directory to C:\temp, then ran the above code and was able to extract all of the serial numbers. Check the $Files variable. Make sure it has the file that you are running against

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
  Select-String -Path C:\temp\files\*.txt -Exclude output.txt -Pattern '(?<=S/N:)\w+(?=\))' -AllMatches | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty matches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
        Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\files\output.txt -Append
```

uses a [lookbehind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to find text after `S\N:` and a [lookahead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) for the end brace `)`

**Note:** this assumes that your text is stored in text files `*.txt`